# Why does my list keep previous values when I restart a scirpt?

Tags: python, list

```
n=8
schedule=input()
First_subject=schedule.split("->")[0]
Second_subject=schedule.split("->")[1]
Third_subject=schedule.split("->")[2]
subjects = [First_subject,Second_subject,Third_subject]

while n==8:
    multianswer = input()

    if str(multianswer.split(":")[0]) == "Add" and  str(multianswer.split(":")[0])  in multianswer and str(multianswer.split(":")[1]) in multianswer:  
        subjects.append(multianswer.split(":")[1])
        print(subjects)

    elif str(multianswer.split(":")[0]) == "Insert" and str(multianswer.split(":")[0]) in multianswer   and str(multianswer.split(":")[1]) in multianswer and str(multianswer.split(":")[2]) in multianswer  :
        subjects.insert(int(multianswer.split(":")[2]) , str(multianswer.split(":")[1]))
        print(subjects)

    elif str(multianswer.split(":")[0]) == "Remove" and str(multianswer.split(":")[0]) in multianswer and str(multianswer.split(":")[1]) in multianswer and str(multianswer.split(":")[1]) in subjects:
        subjects.remove(str(multianswer.split(":")[1]))
        print(subjects)
    
    elif str(multianswer.split(":")[0]) == "Switch" and str(multianswer.split(":")[1] ) in subjects:
        subjects.remove(str(multianswer.split(":")[1])), subjects.append(str(multianswer.append(":")[2]))
        print(subjects)


elif multianswer == "start academy":
        for items in multianswer:
            print(items)
            break
```

Basicly there is a list and it changes according to the variable multianswer. It' used to make a school schedule and you can do all sorts of operations such as: Remove, add, switch, insert a subject. The remove and add option speak for themselves. The switch option is used to remove one element and add another element. (yes I know my remove function is not working properly). And whenever I restart the script some of the old values of the list "subjects" are in the list. How?! Also why the hell aren't my remove, switch and kill functions not working!

Comment: Sorry, but why are you splitting `multianswer` and checking if it is _in_ `multianswer`? It's literally a part of it?

Comment: I am new to python as a whole hahaha. These are just some projects to get me familiar with lists arrays etc

Comment: I read the question before the edit. Your question is the opposite of what I interpreted. Are you using Spyder/jupyter?

Comment: Nope. I only know what they do in theory. I just want to say thank you all for the help. It's crazy how fast I got an answer. The sterotypes about the community seem to be comepletly false!

Comment: What they do is wrap an ipython session in essence. That means that between script runs, they might carry state and stop the script from being fully reset. Do you see the same behaviour if you execute your script from the command line? I just picked the two editors I could think of that intrinsically could do this, but there may be more

Comment: Ye I feel stupid asking but how do I run my script from the **command** line

Comment: Windows or Linux/MacOS?

Comment: Windows 10......

Comment: That makes it harder for me. I can't test that my memory is correct tonight as I'm on Mac right now. If you open powershell or cmd and type `python3` does it do something or throw an error? (If it does something and you want to escape it after the test, type `exit()` and press Enter)

Comment: Fricking error. Damn something is really messed up. Ima take care of it tommorow, it's getting pretty late here, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the whole thing in a `try except` filtering for a `KeyBoardInterrupt`, and then setting the value of `subject` equal to `None`

Like this:

```
 try:
     # your code
 except KeyBoardInterrupt:
     subject = None
     exit()
```